# How to publishing limited function in magento webservices instead of showing all?

Tags: magento, soap, magento-1.7

How to publish limited function in magento soap v2 web services wsdl xml file?

Comment: You need to explain your question a lot more clearly that this.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, thank you for quick response. i mean, when we are using http://domainname.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1, its generating wsdl xml file, we will find all available methods with request string and response string. i don't want to show all methods, i want show only login and required one productUpdate

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can restrict it by adding SOAP role by providing limited access. To do this login to admin panel :

System > Web Services > SOAP/XML-RPC-Roles and create a new roles.

then click on "Role Resources" tab and select custom option from Resource Access dropdown and select roles which you want to expose through API.

After this create new SOAP user or existing user assign your newly created role.

I hope this help!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Satish Sojitra, but this is not right answer... ;), i don't want to show it on that wsdl xml file and i am aware of that role and user

Comment: Have you tried by assigning role and hitting domainname/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 either it's restricted or not.

Comment: @Satush Sojitra, yes, apart from the above solution if you have anything, let me know

Comment: yes, apart from the above solution if you have anything, let me know